# what is rtm webservices?Used to access the data base

Tags: java, database, web-services, jdeveloper, rtm

Hey, you see many times over the internet / resume that "rtm was used to acess database". Please explain in layman terms, if possible. It's related web services. I couldn't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most sites I found say RTM refers to Release To Manufacturing, or when a software is released.

However, your particular quote states: "rtm was used to access database" I thought "release to manufacturing" doesn't make sense here so I did some more digging. I believe the particular statement you have posted indicates that a user used a "Real Time Monitor" to access the database. You can find more information on database monitoring here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_activity_monitoring